# Default layout with 9 columns

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to use LESS framework 4, and i've create this css code:

```
#sponsor .ristorante  {
   width: 92px;
   float:left;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
#sponsor .ristorante .name {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

and in html file:

```
<div id="sponsor">
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO2</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO3</div>
   </div>      
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO4</div>
   </div>      
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO5</div>
   </div>      
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO6</div>
   </div>      
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO7</div>
   </div>      
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO8</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO9</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ristorante">
     <div class="name">RISTO10</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

but in broweser see 9 risto in first line and one risto in seconvd line!

instead, body layout default is width:896 with 10columns

how can i have ten columns??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the width of your elements is pushing the last one to a new line.
10 x divs @ 92px wide each is 920px for all columns. If I understand you correctly you have 896px set. 
 Change your wrapper width to 920px and you'll be ok. OR change your `ristorante` width to 89px

Comment: i changed ristorante to 89px and all is ok! but if than i try yo change 896px with w252px (Mobile Layout: 320px - Gutters: 24px. - Outer margins: 34px.) i see only two columns instead 3 columns! what do you think?

Comment: Play around with the math. It is a simple problem of: you have a fixed width container and you are trying to put multiple items into it that ***may*** cause the elements to stack. if you really don't want the stacking don't define a width to the container. Or set `white-space: nowrap; overflow: visible`

Comment: how can i use "less framework" to get the expected number of columns depending on the device from which i connect?? i need to create 10 div and spread over one or more lines depending on the layout

Comment: What are your desired outputs: Your OP says you want ten a crossed one line but on a mobi browser you want 3 columns ? can you provide the measurements you have taken for widths? As a note: it is generally not a good idea to produce more than two columns for a mobi site. The smartphone / tablet screen sizes are generally too small to display that information nicely. A good solution is to reduce down to two or one column and display all your information as rows. that was the users can vertically scroll through the content instead of horizontally.